# App crashes in iPhone 4 with base SDK 8.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I simply coded an app with Xcode 6.1. I can run the app with all simulators also with devices iPhone 5S, iPhone 4S and iPad retina successfully.

But I sent the app to a friend to test who has iPhone4 and he reports that after seeing main screen, touching a button quits the app. I have no chance to debug it with iPhone4 and also there is no option to test the app in simulator of iPhone4.

Is there any build parameters that I may miss?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post the crash log?  It's impossible for us to debug this without more information.

Comment: Unfortunately crash reporting friend is a regular user and he is out of my country. I understand your comment of impossibility of debugging without any info. But I posted the question for any possible similar experience.

Comment: Okay, what version of iOS is your friend running?

Comment: Your friend can get the crash log in `Settings->General->About->Diagnostics and Usage->LatestCrash-AppName.plist`.  Have him copy and paste it into an email or something.

Comment: I installed IOS 7.1 Simulator and having SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "MissingResource.png" error in simulator 4S (IOS 7.1)

Answer (score 0):

I changed `SKNode`s to `SKSpriteNodes` and now code is working on IOS 7.1 also. `-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime` method was giving error with `SKNodes` in IOS 7.1. It may be a problem of Sprite Kit scene editor came with Xcode 6.Thank you.